# How to create AES encryption and decryption program in symbian

Tags: java, encryption, symbian

I want to create AES encryption and decryption program in symbian which must be compatible with AES encryption in java

Means if I encrypt the data in Symbian I must be able to decrypt the same in java and vice versa

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909180/aes-in-symbian

Answer (score 1):

They have a implementation of AES (encrypt and decrypt) as part of their [main crypto library](http://developer.symbian.com/main/tools_and_sdks/developer_tools/supported/crypto_api/).  Look for CAESEncryptor and CAESDecryptor.  If the Java and Symbian aren't compatible, there's a bug in one.  Good luck finding which. ;)

Comment: How to encrypt the data in symbian which can be decrypted using java and viceversa

Comment: Sunil, what exactly is your question?  Use the Symbian and Java classes with the same options, and that should work.