# How to encrypt a data using symbian C++, so that i can decrypt the same data using java

Tags: c++, encryption, symbian

How to encrypt a data using symbian C++, so that i can decrypt the same data using java

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975618/how-to-create-aes-encryption-and-decryption-program-in-symbian

Comment: I know But I did not get any accurate answer.

Comment: @Sunil: Perhaps you should clarify your old question instead of posting new ones. Asking essentially the same vague question over and over again is not how this site works.

Comment: Actually in java AES encryption is present which is not compatible with that of symbian C++. So how can i encrypt the data in java which is encrypted in symbian

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use any algorithm - it's just that the encoding will be written in C++ and the decoding in Java.

Comment: In Symbian C++ in AES there is only PKCS& and PKCS1Padding, also CBC is the cipher mode. But in java this is not present having all the three combinations

Comment: I'm surprised at that really - sorry I couldn't offer anything more concrete.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a common encryption algorithm like Base64. which is available in both Symbian and Java. In Symbian, TImCodecB64 can be used for Base64 encryption.

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, it's encoding. It takes seconds to "break" it.